# socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, md5

i am trying to make a server-client md5 decription
the server sends how many cores he have(cpu)
and the client slices him th range  for multiproccesing
(brute force)
but the server throws me the "socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" error
any suggestion?

client:

```
import socket
RANGE=10000
d="7a2b33c672ce223b2aa5789171ddde2f"
d=d.lower()
HOMEADDRES='127.0.0.1'
PORT=2345
ADDRESS=(HOMEADDRES,PORT)

my_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET ,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect((HOMEADDRES,PORT))



def main():
    ranges=""
    my_socket.send(d)
    cores=int(my_socket.recv(1024))
    borders=[0]
    for i in range(1,cores+1):
        borders.append(RANGE*i/cores)
    for i in range(len(borders)):
        ranges+=str(borders[i])+"#"
    ranges=ranges[:-1]
    print ranges
    my_socket.send(ranges)
    print my_socket.recv(1024)
    my_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

server:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing
import hashlib

IP_ADD='0.0.0.0'
PORT=2345
ADDRESS = (IP_ADD,PORT)
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(ADDRESS)
server_socket.listen(1)
client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print "connected"

def decrypt(low,high,d):
    print "1"
    i=low
    while i<high:
        m=hashlib.md5()
        m.update(str((i)))
        if m.hexdigest()==d:
            client_socket.send(i)
            client_socket.close()
            server_socket.close()

        i+=1

def main():
    d=client_socket.recv(1024)
    client_socket.send(str(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    borders=client_socket.recv(1024)
    borders=borders.split("#")
    for i in range(len(borders)-1):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=decrypt, args=(borders[i],borders[i+1],d))
        p.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Move the code which is outside `main()` (creating the server socket) to the start of main. You don't show how `main()` is called in the server, I assume it is similar to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your server socket in the module scope so as soon as the module is imported, it is created and bound to (0.0.0.0, 2345).

Multiprocessing will cause the module to be (re)imported in the new process it creates, so that process will immediately try to create the same server socket on port 2345 and that is impossible.

My suggestion is either don't create your server socket in the module scope but do it in main() or move the multiprocessing stuff into its own module.

Comment: what is its own module"

Comment: do i need to write it in a different script and import it?

Comment: yes, create a new module f.ex.  decryption.py and move the actual decryption logic to there. Still, it's also good to not create the socket in module scope.

Comment: what do you men? what is creating a socket without the module?

Comment: Those are basic Python questions, have you an understanding of how modules work in Python? Also both me and cdarke above have already said what to do, move the stuff inside main() or in their own module. That will avoid creating the socket everytime the module is loaded by the process spawned by multiprocessing.

Comment: do i need to call the multiproccesing action from the new module or from my main()?

Comment: cdark's suggestion was not helpfull

Comment: it throws me this error-pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in method recvfrom_into of _socket.socket object at 0x02874160>: it's not found as __main__.recvfrom_into

Comment: Study the documentation and the examples of the multiprocessing module https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines   even more so when you're on Windows because then you have some extra limitations to deal with

Answer (score 0):

The below python idiom solved this for me

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application()
    web.run_app(app)
```